# How can I prevent a secondary condensation drain line from dripping down the side of my house?

Tags: hvac, drain

I have 2 central AC units in my 2 story house.  From what I was told by the last AC repair man that visited, each of my ac units in the crawl space/attic has a main drain line that drains directly into one the sink drains in 2 of my upstairs bathrooms. If those drain lines get clogged, there is a secondary drain line that exits the house through the second story eaves.  So I have 2 small pipes sticking out my second story eaves. Recently one of them starter to drip water, which I guess means that one of my main drain lines is clogged. I've already made an appointment to have the that taken care of.  My question involves the secondary drain pipes.  They only stick out about 1 inch, so when the dirty A/C water does drain/drip from them it "dribbles" all down the side of my house, leaving dirty/rusty stains.  What is the best way to remedy this problem?  A small piece of hose?  Extend the drain pipe?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the water is running along the underside of the pipe back to the house, instead of free-falling off the end. If that's the case, you could just slip an elbow on to the end and point it down. The water won't be able to travel up the elbow to the wall.

Comment: I'd assume that the pipe is already pointed down, though without photos it's impossible to say for sure.  Even so, the water is likely pushed back towards the house by wind.  Extending the pipe away from the house a bit might help, but again, it's hard to say without seeing it. I think the real solution, is to repair the main drain so the secondary is not used.  It sounds like a terrible setup to me, but I'm sure the OP doesn't want to reroute the drain, or have a long tube hanging down the side of their house.